# main demux error: socket bind error: Cannot assign requested address when trying to connect gstreamer and vlc

Tags: sockets, gstreamer, vlc

I am trying to connect with vlc to an embedded board where a gstreamer cmd is executed. However vlc gives me the error:

```
[00007f9734001160] main demux error: socket bind error: Cannot assign requested address
```

The following gstreamer cmd is used:

```
 "appsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! jpegenc ! multipartmux ! tcpserversink name=out-sink host=0.0.0.0 port=7001"
```

And I try to use the following command on the host machine:

```
vlc rtp://192.168.0.10:7001
```

Sadly it does not work, however I can ping from the one machine to the other and vice-versa.

Furthermore, it is a precompiled binary, therefore I am unable to change the gstreamer command and can only adapt the command and utilities used at the host machine.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Please share full VLC logs, share the ping command you use as well

Comment: Try streaming to 127.0.0.1 instead

Comment: And see https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=53475

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my local system with `videotestsrc` instead of your `appsink`.

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! jpegenc ! multipartmux ! tcpserversink name=out-sink host=0.0.0.0 port=7001
```

Please note that you are transmitting over TCP and without RTP payloading so instead of `rtp://..` I listened with `tcp://` and vlc was able to open.

```
vlc tcp://127.0.0.1:7001
```

If you still want to use rtp I would recommend that you use `rtpjpegpay`, and some sdp file like

```
v=0
m=video 7001 RTP/AVP 26
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
a=rtpmap:26 JPEG/90000
```